# OS X llvm-gcc output ELF

Tags: macos, llvm

Is it possible to compile a c file into an elf on OS X using llvm-gcc? If so, how? I've only been able to get mach-o output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clang` will take options like `-ccc-host-triple i686-pc-linux-gnu`, but on OS X it will obviously fail in the link step.

You could just run a Linux VM in OS X (VirtualBox is free VM host application) and build the ELF natively.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can build a cross-compiler, or just install one with fink or macports.